# Google appengine, least expensive way to run heavy datastore write cron job?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, cron

I have a Google appengine application, written in Go, that has a cron process which runs once a day at 3am.  This process looks at all of the changes that have happened to my data during the day and stores some meta data about what happened.  My users can run reports on this meta data to see trends that have happened over several months.  The process does around 10-20 million datastore writes every night.  It all works just fine, but since I have started running it I have noticed a significant increase in my monthly bill from Google (from around $50/month to around $400/month).

I have just setup a very basic taskqueue that this runs in, I have not changed the default settings at all.  Is there a better way that I could be running this process at night that could save me money?  I have never messed around with the backends (which are now depreciated) or the modules api, and I know they've changed a lot of this stuff recently so I'm not sure where to start looking.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 10-20 million writes for "some meta data" seems awfully a lot.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your costs are driven by these datastore writes (since you are not using a backend, instance hours is not an issue). How you do them (at night, using a cron job, on backends, etc.) does not matter.

Comment: I suppose part of the issue is that I don't know exactly what I'm trying to ask because I'm not very familiar with backends/modules (or other options) and what their specific benefits are.  But you have a good point, if my cost is driven by the write ops, and the main benefit of backends/modules is cheaper instance hours, then they would not help.  I suppose I will have to take the long road and look into making my logic and data structure more efficient instead.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your instances at 3am. It might be that GAE spins up a lot of them to handle the job. You could configure your job to make it run less paralel so it will take longer but perhaps it will need only 1 instance then.
However, if your database writes are indeed the biggest factor this won't make a big impact.

You can try looking at your data models and indexes. Remember that each indexed field costs 2 writes extra, so see if you can remove indexes from some fields if you don't need them.

Comment: Thank you, Christiaan, very helpful advice.  I think the main problem lies with my data model, just too many writes are required to do what I am doing.  I'm a fairly new convert from SQL to BigTable, so I have definitely made some mistakes along the way.  I have learned the importance of knowing ahead of time what you will want to do with the data in the end (I wish my boss could actually tell me what he wanted me to do with the data, that would greatly help).  Again, thank you for the input on such a vague question.

Answer (score 1):

One improvement that you can do is to batch your write operations, you can use memcache for this (pay the dedicated one since it's more reliable). Write the updates to memcache, once it's about 900K, flush it to datastore. This will reduces the number of write to datastore A LOT, especially if your metadata's size is small.

Comment: 1) Interesting... I didn't realize that would help.  I thought (but am open to being made fun of if I'm totally wrong) that the number of writes depended on the data structure and indexes, not how often I actually called the datastore.Put() method.

Comment: 2) I didn't realize there was a "reliable" memcache, the docs I read said to use memcache as if the data may disappear at any time.  If that is true, isn't it entirely possible that the data I am temporarily keeping in memcache could just get lost?  I can't afford to lose any of this data, although I guess I could validate it before I write it to the datastore.  My strategy has been to store data in it after I pull it out of the datastore, but to erase it from memcache after I write an update to the datastore.

Comment: 1) It would since you reduce your datastore write operation by. Let me clarify, instead of writing N rows to datastore directly, you write them into a single entry in memcache, and when it's almost full, you write the entry in memcache into a single entry in datastore. This will reduce the datastore operations. However this will only work if your entry is small (but many of them) and the downside is, you cannot query it back.
2. possible in theory, that's just based on my experience that the dedicated is more reliable. Since you have a dedicated size for you instead of shared with other apps.

Comment: I think I'm confused.  Why would you ever want to store something if you can't query it back?  I definitely need to re-query the data that I am storing, the whole reason I am creating it in the first place is to provide a filterable report for my users.  My data has values like Date, Department, Location, etc., with a numeric value attached.  So my report needs to be able to pull all entries for a given date range, department, location, etc, and add up all the numeric values (and display several other string values), so it definitely needs to be query-able.

Comment: For analytics purposes, you do not need to query from appengine. So store it in the cheapest possible way, and dump it to another database that is built for analytics :)

Comment: Hm... that sounds like more work than I had hoped, but you may be on to something.